# Access Run-time Error 2475 *occasionally* occuring

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an error log that logs in the access table whenever a runtime error occurs for a user in the error trapper, and a particular error seems to occur for 10 random users, every hour at least.

This error appears to occur completely at random, on a random module with the Set ActiveForm code, with random users at random intervals. As far as I can see, there is no pattern between the users.

> 2475 - "You entered an expression that requires a form to be the active window".

This appears to occur in any of the modules that contain any of the setting of a form. I am using the following lines:

```
Dim af as Object
Set af = Screen.ActiveForm
```

I have tried using alternatives, such as declaring it as Form, and also tried the below:

```
Dim sstatus as String
Dim ps as String

If DLookup("[TM_UserType]", "[SD_Teams]", "[TM_username]= '" & usernm & "'") = "adj" Then
    sstatus = "adj"
Else
    sstatus = "tm"
End If

ps = "frmProdSubmit_" & sstatus
```

Then referencing the form this way:

```
Forms(ps).cmbTeam.Value = ""
```

But this **still** causes the same issue, even removing the ActiveForm part.

The last thing to mention (as I believe they could be factors) is that the front end is accessed through a shortcut, which minimises the Access window. Not sure if this could be the culprit, or if the user clicking another application can remove the focus.

The back-end of the database is also accessed by up to around 700 users each day.

As it stands, the error trapper pops up with the message, but the front end continues working correctly. It's just an annoying issue to resolve, but am slowly running out of ideas now, and any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I've found `Screen.ActiveForm` to generally be used when something more robust could be employed. So what is the objective of your code here, from a higher level perspective ?

Comment: Is there any need for the use of `screen` or `af` can you not replace `af` with `me` or rather than the form object `me.name`?

Comment: In this particular example @Minty - it's setting the RecordSource of a subform based on variables selected on said form. The error does occur on various modules though. I can't use Me unfortunately as the code isn't in a Private Sub.

Comment: I'm still not following why you need to know the active form. If the goal is to have a subform communicate with a parent form then it's not needed. You can either reference the child form directly from the parent (or vice versa) or, if there's a possibility of reusing the child form somewhere else, you can use events to move data between the forms. There is also a much looser coupling between forms with events facilitating the communication.

Comment: Are you making sure the form is actually open before trying to make it active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 2475 is thrown when a non-form object is the active screen object such as a table datasheet. I've encountered this error in an application that uses multiple instances of a form and needs to track whether the multiple form module is active or one of the other application module functions in which case all instances of the multiple forms (popups) need to have .visible set to false. I use the Screen.ActiveForm.Name call in the Form_Deactivate event.

You can trap the error in the procedure's error handler and take action knowing the screen's active object is not a form.

```
Example:

Private Sub Form_Deactivate()
  On Error GoTo errHandler
  
  If Screen.ActiveForm.Name <> "AnApplicationForm" Then 'throws 2475 if not a form object
    sstatus = "status message"
  End If
ExitSub:
  Exit Sub
errHandler:
  If Err.Number = 2475 Then Resume Next 'screen active object is not a form i.e. datasheet
  MsgBox "Error in " & Me.Name & ".Form_Deactivate: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ExitSub
End Sub 'Form_Deactivate
```